# Huawei Modem port number not showing up

Tags: modem

I tried configuring the modem dongle for Raspberry Pi 4 but the port number is not showing up.
Under `ifconfig` I see eth1
I tried looking under `dmesg` command I can't see anything. I looked for all the devices I got this picture no clue to the port number( e.g USB0, USB1, USB2, USB3) because I want to use it for `wvdial` configuration. [image: the list of the devices connected but the modem isn't there] I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: DO NOT post pictures of text - post text!

Comment: have you tried using `lsusb` to list usb devices

Comment: Lsusb shows the modem was detected, I was just not able to figure out the USB port